# How to get filename of the file downloaded by wget

Tags: python, python-2.7, wget

I'm using `os.system('wget '+ link)` to retrieve files from websites. After downloading, I want to further process these files based on the source links.

Most of the links are of this form
`htttp://example.com/.../filename.zip` .
In such cases, the file is simply downloaded as `filename.zip`. This I can extract from the link using both `basename` as well as  RegExp `[^/]+$`.

But the problem is links of the form

```
http://http://www.ez-robot.com
http://www.worldscientific.com/
http://www.fairweld.com
```

These links are downloaded as `index.html`, `index.html.1`,`index.html.2` ans so on.
Here, I'm not able to differentiate which `index` file belong to which website. One way I can do this is by looking at the order in which links are passed to `wget`.

I want some general method to get 'real' file name by which file is downloaded in the computer. When `wget` completes execution, it shows on terminal a  `Saving to:` label followed by that 'real' file name. I want to store that file name in a string.

Does there exists any direct/easier method to get the filename ? And I'm using Python.

```
$ wget http://www.fairweld.com
--2015-04-11 18:51:48--  http://www.fairweld.com/
Connecting to 202.142.81.24:3124... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 39979 (39K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use os.path.basename and get the name depending on how the url ends, you can also use requests to download the html:

```
links = ["http://www.ez-robot.com",
"http://www.worldscientific.com/",
"http://www.fairweld.com"]


import urlparse
import requests
import os
for link in links:
    r = requests.get(link)
    if link.rsrip("/").endswith(".com"):
        name = os.path.basename(link)
    else:
        name = urlparse.urlsplit(link.path.split("/")[-1])
    with open("{}.html".format(name),"w") as f:
        f.write(r.content)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are experiencing happens because the filename already exists. I would suggest downloading every 'file' to a new folder (i.e. the domain name) to prevent duplicates.

`$ wget --directory-prefix=$DOMAIN $URL`

This will preserve the original filename, as specified in the headers of the data.

One more tip, you are using `os.system('wget '+ link)` which can be very unsafe as you are not sanitising your input here. Input can be subject to injections, which can make your system run unwanted commands. Read more on [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).